# How to write Cyrillic text in C++ console

Tags: c++, encoding, character-encoding

For example, if I write:

```
cout << "Привет!" << endl; //it's hello in Russian
```

In the console it would be something like `╧ЁштхЄ!`.

OK, I know that we can use:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
```

But after that, command line arguments in Russian do not work (if I start my program through a BAT file):

**StartProgram.bat**

```
chcp 1251
MyProgram.exe -user=Олег -password=Пароль
```

So, after `setlocale` the program can't read Russian arguments properly.

This happens because the BAT file in CP1251, but the console is in CP866.

So, there is a question:

How can I write Russian text in the C++ console and at the same time have Russian command line arguments read properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this entry from Michael Kaplan's blog:

http://www.siao2.com/2008/03/18/8306597.aspx

Comment: Thanks, it works!

But in this way I can't use cout, only wprintf

Comment: `wcout`  is the equivalent of `wprintf` just like `cout` is the equivalent of `printf` - the last two won't do Unicode.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using `wcout`? It is similar to `cout`, but it accepts "wide" characters, which should permit the proper unicode encodings.

This [article about localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292604(VS.71).aspx), and [another](http://www.siao2.com/2008/03/18/8306597.aspx), both from MSDN may be of use.

Comment: Unless I am completely mistaken, unicode will be a necessity for cyrillic. Regular 8-bit ASCII does not have glyphs for most of the characters in the cyrillic alphabet. The console output from your example (`╧ЁштхЄ`) is composed of some exotic 8-bit ASCII characters because the correct characters aren't available in that encoding.

Comment: Hmm.. Windows cyrillic is 1251 (Windows-1251) codepage. But DOS cyrillic uses 866 codepage.
So, "Привет!" in CP1251 = "╧ЁштхЄ!" in CP866.

This is what happened, I write in C++ as cp1251, but console shows it as cp866.

Comment: Ah, the joys of character encodings :)

Comment: Don't forget if you're using wcout to put `L` in front of all your literals. Therefore, `wcout << L"Привет!" << endl;` in your example.

Comment: thanks, but this not working too, I think because I don't use Unicode

Comment: @VextoR: start using it. Look at MichKap's blog again (see other link) - Microsoft "supports" 8 bit encodings for _legacy_ reasons. In particular, they are unlikely to change things, even when you'd consider them bugs - changing them would risk breaking the old programs, without any benefit for the newer Unicode apps.

Answer (score 3):

Console set to be in 1251 instead of in 866:

```
 //Save As Windows 1251
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<windows.h>
    int main(int argc, char **argv){ 
        SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
        SetConsoleCP(1251);
        if(argc<2)return 0;
        else printf("Hello %s %s\n",argv[1],argv[2]);
    }
```

Program is argument.exe and result:

D:\Debug>argument Олег Пароль
Hello Олег Пароль

Comment: The code file should be also saved in Cyrillic (Windows) Codepage (1251).

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the following functions [`setlocale()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/clocale/setlocale/) and [`SetConsoleOutputCP()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686036%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
SetConsoleOutputCP(866);
```

Comment: This one helped me a lot. One more we need to add - you should use `#include <locale>`

Answer (score 1):

For me this seems to resolve the problem:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wcout << L"Огњен" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the language for non-unicode programs to be Russian, in the Regional and Language Options section of the Control Panel?

(I have no idea what the usual setup for Russian-speaking programmers might be; I just wonder whether it is common to set this to some kind of English to avoid confusing overly-parochial tools.)

Unless my memory is playing tricks, when I was working with some code from Japanese developers it was this step that got the console displaying non-Unicode Japanese text (Shift-JIS encoding) properly.

Answer (score 0):

**WriteConsoleW** can handle UNICODE e.g. Cyrillic letters without problems. If you won’t miss the formatting features of **wcout**, you can redirect the standard **wcout** stream buffer and print it with **WriteConsoleW**.

[A full example is shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27066396/1376730)

```
// save and redirect cout buffer
wostringstream  newCoutBuffer;
wstreambuf*     oldCoutBuffer = wcout.rdbuf(newCoutBuffer.rdbuf());    

// do your wcout stuff here
// do your wcout stuff here

DWORD dwWritten;
WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), newCoutBuffer.str().c_str(),newCoutBuffer.tellp(),&dwWritten,NULL);  

// restore cout buffer
wcout.rdbuf(oldCoutBuffer);
```

Answer (score -1):

The most correct way is using wcout + std::imbue.

But one should know that there was some changes in setlocale API which happened in Windows Vista/7. "Russian" locale string isn't recognized as "cp866" anymore, at least in Visual C++ CRT.

To get cp866 output, try use this instead:

```
::setlocale( LC_ALL , "russian_russia.866" );
```