# Cant output non english characters in VS code

Tags: c++

I am new to programming, currently I am trying to output "Привет мир" (which is "Hello world") but I get ???? and some weird blocks, i have tried many solutions, but it doesnt help, can anyone please help me so that I could output russian text properly?

Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout <<"Привет мир";
}
```

Comment: Mostly, this is related to your terminal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write Cyrillic text in C++ console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261496/how-to-write-cyrillic-text-in-c-console)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the encoding settings?

There is a list of encodings in VS Code when you click on the lower right status bar where the encoding is shown. Choose to either reopen the file with a specific encoding or save the file with a specific encoding.